# How to use Condition in Delphi Breakpoint properties

Tags: delphi, debugging, conditional-breakpoint

I found that a nested loop fails when some particular condition is reached, somehow when I = 1, J = 3 and k = 5

I tried to right click on the breakpoint and in the condition I set

(I = 1) and (J = 3) AND (K = 5)

anyway the breakpoint doesn't stop...

What is wrong?

Comment: no one have ever faced such a problem please post the code

Comment: ok, my mistake. By the way debugging undocumented nested loops written by others in bad design is an hell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just tried that in D2007 and it works fine. what version are you using?

```
procedure TForm85.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var i,j,k : integer;
    z:integer;
begin

  for i := 0 to 10 do
  for j := 0 to 10 do
  for k := 0 to 10 do
  BEGIN
    z := z + i * j * k; // breakpoint on this line.
  END;

  ShowMessage(IntToStr(z));
end;
```

Have you considered that the breakpoint may not be reached because the condition is not being met?

Comment: don't worry about versions this can be done in turbo pascal too

Comment: @Vibeeshan: Yes, but different versions of Delphi will have different bugs :-(

Comment: Ok thanks I simply was testing the wrong condition (like J had an impossible value, simple typing mistake).... Wow thanks to all for the many replies. It is the first time I used this feature I shold have made a sample project with 1 condition to test how it works. Anyway now it is clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You did add the breakpoint as a **Breaking breakpoint** I assume.

To verify this

- open the Breakpoint properties window
- click on Advanced
- make sure the *Break* checkbox is checked.

Comment: Just a clarification: To open the "Breakpoint Properties dialog" one has to right-click the red dot in the IDE not the breakpoint entry into the "Breakpoints" panel.

Answer (score 1):

May be according to your code

```
(I = 1) and (J = 3) AND (K = 5)
```

may never get this values at same time

Answer (score 0):

Set breakpoint on a line of code before the condition is met and step through with F8?